# spring jpa two ManyToOne foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;
    String email;
    String password;

    @Column(unique = true)
    String username;

}
```

game table as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "games")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user1;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user2;
}
```

when i try to insert record it gave error :

detached entity passed to persist: ttt.model.User;

Comment: Provide more code, how are you persisting entities? Which code line gives you exact exception?

Comment: Shouldn't a `Game` have a `@OneToMany` relationship with `User`? In which case, you would probably want to use some Collection of `User` for the `Game` entity. What do I know, I may be wrong. You haven't really explained much.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate persist method is meant to move an Entity [from the NEW state to MANAGED one](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed). Once you have associated an Entity to a given persistence Context you should use merge, instead of persist.

Now, I think your mappings are not following the standard ORM entity association standards.

1. Is it that the Game should always contain 2 users?
2. The user shouldn't have an association back to a Game?

These questions are really important, wince you regularly have a parent association side and a children association side. It is the parent that needs to be saved first and then the children.

That is because the child has a FK association to the parent and in case it's marked as NOT NULL then it's understandable why the parent needs to be saved first.